# Cannot write to MemoryStream using BinaryWriter

Tags: c#, stream

I've tried this code:

```
byte[] someData = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(someData, 1, someData.Length - 1, true);
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(1);
}
stream.Dispose();
```

Everytime it's run, a NotSupportedException is thrown, telling me that the stream cannot be written to. Why is this the case? The last parameter of the initialization shown in line 2 clearly is true, so I should be able to write to the stream.
It works if I don't specify the start index and count.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk6t72e.aspx):

> Initializes a new **non-resizable** instance of the MemoryStream class
>   based on the specified region of a byte array, with the CanWrite
>   property set as specified.

The `BinaryWriter` starts writing at the end of the stream, so it needs to resize it to be able to write, but this is not allowed. You can only write to the already allocated bytes of the stream.

Comment: See [Mudx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9057835/199364) for what to do instead. Specifically, OP needs to use a *different constructor*; then they can get the desired behavior. [In their case, it means they need to first either (a) copy the data they wish to stream, or (b) make an enumerator that streams the desired data.]

Answer (score 14):

Always (almost always) create a memory stream without parameters in the constructor:

```
 using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write(1);
            }
            stream.Flush();
            byte[] bytes = stream.GetBuffer();
            //use it
        }
```

This code works fine

Comment: Thanks. That indeed works. I'll have to copy the contents of someData manually since I don't want the first index to be in the Stream, but that's not that bad.

Comment: @haiyyu - note that an alternative to copying the data is to make an enumerator that returns the desired data as a stream.